# I Cant install puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, e2e-testing

I ran this script -> `npm i --save-dev puppeteer` to install `puppeteer` for e2e testing purposes.

But there is an error while installing:

```
C:\Users\Mora\Desktop\JS\Testing>npm i --save-dev puppeteer

> puppeteer@13.1.3 install C:\Users\Mora\Desktop\JS\Testing\node_modules\puppete
er
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r950341! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env vari
able to skip download.
Error: Download failed: server returned code 403. URL: https://storage.googleapi
s.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/950341/chrome-win.zip
    at C:\Users\Mora\Desktop\JS\Testing\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer
\node\BrowserFetcher.js:367:27
    at ClientRequest.requestCallback (C:\Users\Mora\Desktop\JS\Testing\node_modu
les\puppeteer\lib\cjs\puppeteer\node\BrowserFetcher.js:493:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:483:26)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient (_http_client.js:647:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:126:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:515:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
npm WARN js-testing-introduction@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fse
vents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32"
})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\wa
tchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"ia32
"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puppeteer@13.1.3 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puppeteer@13.1.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mora\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-06T10_19_25_3
69Z-debug.log
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

// do not install a puppeteer

ran this script -> npm install --ignore-scripts puppeteer

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32138718)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is not able to download chromium from https://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/Win/950341/chrome-win.zip.

Check whether your network is e.g behind a proxy or `storage.googleapis.com` was blocked by the firewall.